# Reset validation messages for date time pickers is not working

Tags: kendo-ui

I have kendo date time pickers with validations.I want to reset that validation messages on reset button click.When we click on reset button reset the validation messages.I tried that one but it is not working.
This is my reset code

```
         $("#clear").click(function(){
       $("#datetimepicker").find("span.k-tooltip-validation").hide();
        $("#datetimepicker1").find("span.k-tooltip-validation").hide();


         });
```

MY bin is http://jsbin.com/ufimom/159/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("#datetimepicker span.k-tooltip-validation").hide();
$("#datetimepicker1 span.k-tooltip-validation").hide();
```

Greetings,

Comment: Ya Thank you for your quick reply,I tried this one but no result http://jsbin.com/ufimom/161/edit

Comment: The above didn't work. Neither did `Siblings` mentioned in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872632/hide-the-validation-error