# Hide the validation error?

Tags: kendo-ui

Here issue is validation is working fine for datetimepickers but while click reset button valaidation is must hide how to do?  fiddle:http://jsbin.com/ufimom/167/edit
    code

```
    $("#clear").click(function(){
    $("#datetimepicker").find("span.k-tooltip").hide();
    $("#datetimepicker1").find("span.k-tooltip").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sandeep, Try this..

```
$("#clear").click(function(){
 $("#datetimepicker").siblings("span.k-tooltip-validation").hide();    
 $("#datetimepicker1").siblings("span.k-tooltip-validation").hide();                                
});
```

Its work fine.
 jsfiddle http://jsbin.com/ufimom/172/edit

Comment: You had not defined validate() method. It shows this error in browser console.

Comment: Still I get message.. though I tried both `find` & `Siblings` :(

Comment: It will work.. Post your sample code in jsfiddle or jsbin. So that i can help you